# How to parse a Link for only the actual domain and not www?

Tags: php, parsing

I am using PHP url Parse below is the code I am using

```
$parse = (object)parse_url($arr[1]);
            if(!property_exists($parse, 'host') || $parse->host === "") {
                return;
            }
```

In above code for example if I feed below link

https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2019/07/17

The above code returns "www.forbes.com" but I need only "forbes.com" how do I achieve it.

Comment: `www.` _is_ the actual domain. The fact that `forbes.com` might serve the website is no guarantee. That said, you can use someting like `substr` to take off the first 4 characters if you really want it.

Comment: Do you intend the same functionality for `blog.example.com` or `mail.example.com`? Or just for `www`?

Comment: @ceejayoz Only for www for blog.example.com etc I have different parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parse = (object)parse_url($arr[1]);
if(!property_exists($parse, 'host') || $parse->host === "") {
    return;
}else{
    if(stripos($parse->host, 'www.') === 0){
        $parse->host = substr($parse->host, strlen('www.'));
    }
}
```

You can use [stripos](https://www.php.net/stripos) to check whether is the first letters is www. then removing it by [substr](https://www.php.net/substr).

Comment: You're Welcome, It's a pleasure to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $input = 'www.google.co.uk/';

    // in case scheme relative URI is passed, e.g., //www.google.com/
     $input = trim($input, '/');

   // If scheme not included, prepend it
     if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
      $input = 'http://' . $input;
     }

     $urlParts = parse_url($input);

  // remove www
    $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

  echo $domain;

 // output: google.co.uk
```